# Allow Java applet to file system access and recording without modifying java policy file?

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet, policyfiles

I'm writing java applet sound recorder, so it needs to have recording permission and also needs to have file access (for storing tmp files during mp3 conversion). It's an intranet application which will run on couple hundreds machines so I wonder if it is possible to achieve that without modifying policy file and granting permissions on each machine.

Comment: I think applets run inside a sandbox and they cannot interact easily with the system and are not allowed by the JVM to access the system resources for security purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> ..so I wonder if it is possible to achieve that without modifying policy file and granting permissions on each machine.

Sure.  Digitally sign the code using a valid code signing certificate, and get the user to tick the 'always allow' check box when launching the app.

Unless you mean 'without digitally signing the code'.  Then - no, it isn't.