# Can't run a simple JavaFX in a Browser packaged by Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, javafx, applet

I created the standard NetBeans JavaFX application and I tried to run it in a browser but I had no luck. I have followed every instruction out there with no luck. I am not doing anything special, standard JavaFX and built it with NetBeans IDE.

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
CacheEntry[file:/Users/mo/NetBeansProjects/WebAppTest/dist/WebAppTest.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Fri Mar 04 07:03:31 EST 2016,length=19089
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1294)
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:717)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:133)
        at java.io.File.getAbsolutePath(File.java:556)
        at webapptest.WebAppTest.start(WebAppTest.java:24)
        at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:134)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
        at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:150)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.dir" "read")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.FXAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1294)
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:717)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:133)
        at java.io.File.getAbsolutePath(File.java:556)
        at webapptest.WebAppTest.start(WebAppTest.java:24)
        at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:134)
        ... 4 more
```

JavaFX application:

FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="webapptest.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

main method

```
public class WebAppTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("FXMLDocument.fxml");
        String filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(filePath));
        System.out.println(filePath);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Due to the Certificate signing issues: I manually trusted the dist\ directory:

Regarding the FXML File, If I didn't do getAbsolutePath(); and I get the resources using the line code below. I get a different error message:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

if I didn't use  getAbsolutePath() I get the following error:

```
updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Mar 04 09:12:56 EST 2016,length=19089
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at webapptest.WebAppTest.start(WebAppTest.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:134)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at webapptest.WebAppTest.start(WebAppTest.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(FXApplet2.java:134)
    ... 4 more

Here is the content of the Jar file:
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you updated your answer, it's now clear what you actually want to do. Instead of converting a classpath resource (as retrieved with `getClass().getResource()`) to a file, you should just use the resource directly:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

You do not want to deal with the `File` class at all, since the resource is coming from inside of a JAR file. Ditch all of that code.

Also, make sure you have the `FXMLDocument.fxml` placed inside of the `webapptest` package. If you have it placed at the root of the classpath, use `.getResource("/FXMLDocument.fxml")` instead.

To include what has been mentioned in comments: You might need to clean and rebuild your project in order for the resources to show up properly.

Comment: it's inside the package and I get java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.

Comment: Please check your build setup (make sure to include eventual resource folders, if you have any). Also, you are sure you are placing the FXMLDocument.fxml into the same directory as the sources?

Comment: Please also look into the compiled `.jar` file that you want to run. Is the FXML file in the `webapptest/` directory?

Comment: Please give `getClass().getResource("/webapptest/FXMLDocument.fxml")` a try

Comment: I did clean rebuild and it started working. Thanks for your dedication to get my issue resolved. I greatly appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are denied permission to the filesystem.

In order for your applet to receive file system permissions, it must either be signed with a code certificate (which costs money) or you need to add a security exception in the Java applet policy file.

Also see:

- [Allow Java applet to file system access and recording without modifying java policy file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26105184/4464702)
- [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)
- [Creating a Trusted Applet with Local File System Access Rights](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3303561/Creating-a-Trusted-Applet-with-Local-File-System-Access-Rights.htm)
- [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: I trusted the entire dist/ and I still can't connect. I updated the question please take a look. Thanks!